# formatting error with Eclipse Mars

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, format

I am using Eclipse Mars to write my Java code. When I use Ctrl-/ to comment some lines and then apply Ctrl-Shift-F to format them and then un-comment the lines, it turns out to *two lines* of code instead of just the original one:

`System.out.printf("%s => Cowz Testing: testing Add a Representative\n",
new Date());`

Instead of that, I wish `new Date());` to be at the end of first line.

**Edit**: The right sequence of steps to reproduce my error have been perfectly described in Jonah Graham's answer.

Comment: What's the error? It's valid Java.

Comment: Sounds to me like you should use Eclipse Luna then.

Comment: This may be of interest https://www.bsi-software.com/en/scout-blog/article/use-the-latest-neon-version-of-the-formatter-with-mars.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I can't see exactly the error you have faced, but I have seen something similar.)

Starting with some code like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.printf("%s => Cowz Testing: testing Add a Representative\n", new Date());
    }
```

Then, comment out the `printf` line, so it now looks like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
//       System.out.printf("%s => Cowz Testing: testing Add a Representative\n", new Date());
    }
```

Apply formatting and the result you have is this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // System.out.printf("%s => Cowz Testing: testing Add a
        // Representative\n", new Date());
    }
```

Uncomment the code and you have an error because the string is not terminated:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.printf("%s => Cowz Testing: testing Add a
        Representative\n", new Date());
    }
```

If the above describes your issue, then I recommend disabling `Enable line comment formatting` in your code style.

### How to do it

1. From the `Window` menu, select `Preferences`
2. Select `Java` / `Code Style` / `Formatter`
3. Press `Edit...`
4. In `Comments` tab, uncheck `Enable line comment formatting` (see screenshot)

[image: disable]

5. If you are editing a built-in profile, provide a new name
6. Press OK twice

Now when you comment out code, it will not edit the contents of comments when you format your code.

You can still use `/* */` comments to have reflowed comments, i.e. for "real" comments, not temporarily commented out code.

Finally, I would recommend that you apply the code style to your projects in addition to your workspace to ensure your whole team shares a code style.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter
Click Edit
Select the Line Wrapping tab
Uncheck Force split, even if line shorter than maximum line width (...)

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed Eclipse Mars had other bugs in formatting, for example when using tabs for indentation. In this [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=467229) it's explained a workaround consisting in setting the indentation policy to spaces only, set the same value to tab size and indentation size, and then switch back to tabs only.

Comment: This bug is now fixed in Mars.1, so a simple update should solve that problem. Separately there is a new formatter being written for Eclipse Neon, a prerelease can be installed in Mars: https://www.bsi-software.com/en/scout-blog/article/use-the-latest-neon-version-of-the-formatter-with-mars.html